# Complete user profiles

Tags: mongoose, jwt, passport.js, mern

I wanna to do a "Complete user profile" for the current logged in user, but when I test the api with the postman, the give result shown "unauthorized". BTW I am using passport middleware. Any tips and helps are much appreciated in advance :)

below is my update code:

```
router.post('/myprofile', passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false}),
(req,res)=>{
    const {errors, isValid}= validateProfileInput(req.body);
    if(!isValid){
        res.status(400).json(errors);
    }
    const profileFields={};
    profileFields.user =req.user.id;
    if(req.body.icNumber)profileFields.icNumber= req.body.icNumber;
    if(req.body.phoneNumber)profileFields.phoneNumber= req.body.phoneNumber;
    if(req.body.dob)profileFields.dob= req.body.dob;
    if(req.body.gender)profileFields.gender= req.body.gender;
    if(req.body.address1)profileFields.address1= req.body.address1;
    if(req.body.address2)profileFields.address2= req.body.address2;
    if(req.body.city) profileFields.city=req.body.city;
    if(req.body.state) profileFields.state=req.body.state;
    if(req.body.zip) profileFields.zip=req.body.zip;

    Profile.findOne({user:req.user.id}).then(profile=>{
        if(profile){
            //update
            Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
                {user:req.user.id},
                {$set: profileFields},
                {$set: { status: true }}
            ).then(profile=>{
                res.json(profile);
            })
            // save profile
            new Profile(profileFields).save().then(profile=>res.json(profile))
        }
    })
  }
)
```

Postman header:
[image]

postman body:
[image]

postman result:
[image]

Comment: There is an `Authorization` tab, next to the headers that you should be using. Have you tried that?

Comment: `passport.authenticate('jwt'...`means the strategy is `jwt` and therefore the authorization header should be `Authorization: jwt eyJ....`

Comment: i have tried sinanspd and jps suggested ans, but it cant works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `jwt` for creating token, use a function that create a token based your own data...finally token is `token: "Bearer " + signedToken`, like this...

```
const jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');
function issueJWT(user) {
  const _id = user._id;

  const expiresIn = '1d';

  const payload = {
    sub: _id,
    iat: Date.now()
  };

  const signedToken = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { expiresIn: expiresIn, algorithm: 'RS256' });

  return {
    token: "Bearer " + signedToken,
    expires: expiresIn
  }
}
```

when you want to get request set your postman like this

[image]

or in header Authorization Key: Breare + spcace + Token